# Should I pass viewModelScope.coroutineContext to liveData builder function?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

[viewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) is used to bind a coroutine lifetime to the `ViewModel` lifecycle. [liveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) builder creates a `LiveData` that runs a coroutine, which lifetime is bound to the `LiveData` state, so, when the `LiveData` isn't active, the coroutine cancels after a timeout. Because of the timeout, the coroutine won't be cancelled on configuration change.

If I create a `LiveData` via `liveData` builder inside a `ViewModel`, and observe that `LiveData` in the `Activity`, `LiveData` lifecycle is already bound to the `Activity` lifecycle. Should I additionally pass the `viewModelScope.coroutineContext` to the `liveData` builder? I think that I shouldn't, but in one of the Android documentation [samples](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) it passes:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val userId: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val user = userId.switchMap { id ->
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(database.loadUserById(id))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the live data can only be passed to the LifecycleOwner that is in “STARTED” or “RESUMED” state. So while running the couroutine in `viewModelScope` observers may not receive data emitted if they are outside these states.

Comment: Were you intending to use `viewModelScope`?  Your question is a bit complicated to follow.  Why not use LiveData scope (`lifecycle-livedata-ktx`)

Comment: how you're going to trigger user  `liveData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q:** `LiveData` lifecycle is already bound to the `Activity` lifecycle. Should I pass the `viewModelScope` to the `liveData` builder?

In simple cases, when an Activity has just one `ViewModel`, the `Activity` lifecycle is the same as the `ViewModel` lifecycle, and it shouldn't change anything, whether you pass 'viewModelScope' to the `lifeData` builder or not. But in more complex cases, for example, when the `ViewModel` [is shared](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) between fragments, the `Fragment` lifecycle may not match the shared `ViewModel` lifecyle, in such cases starting of the coroutine within 'viewModelScope.coroutineContext' makes sense.

---

So, you can use **`viewModelScope`** to provide context to your **`liveData`** builder.

Why?

> **According to [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope):** A `ViewModelScope` is defined for each
>   `ViewModel` in your app. Any **coroutine** launched in this scope is
>   automatically canceled if the **`ViewModel` is cleared**.

So, it helps **cancelling current job** in your `LiveData` because, it's now bounded to your `ViewModelScope`.

Additionally, `viewModelScope` is helpful if you are *computing some data* for a layout, you should scope the work to the `ViewModel` so that if the `ViewModel` is cleared, the work is *canceled automatically* to avoid consuming resources.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a little: "although you're bounded LiveData to Activity lifecycle, ViewModel from which LiveData you're observing is also bounded to Same Activity lifecycle.". If the coroutine lifetime is already bound to the Activity, the coroutine will be cancelled when the Activity is destroyed. If I additionally pass viewModelScope context to the coroutine, what it changes?

Comment: So, If I [share a ViewModel between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing), the coroutine lifecycle should be bound to that ViewModel, yes, it makes sense. I didn't think about this case, when ViewModel lifecycle differs from the LifecycleOwner lifecycle. It is what I asked for, could you update you answer? Then I can accept it.

Comment: ~"**cancelling current job**".  Who should be doing this?

Comment: If you pass view model scope along to live data builder then it gets cancelled once view model scope gets cancelled. In our cases once view model reaches on clear state.